# Can I create beautiful buttons inside a form_for helper?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, button, submit, form-for

I have a login form thanks to form_for helper and in my opinion it has an ugly button styling.

[image]

And I would like to have a button similar to this.

[image]

I'm wondering is there any way to customize form_for submit button?

**_form.html**

## Log In

```
<%= form_tag '/authenticate' do %>
  <div class="email">
    <%= label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </div>
  <div class="password">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
    <%= submit_tag "Log In" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `bootstrap` as CSS Framework, so you can do this:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Log In', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the submit button, and then give style to that class.

```
<%= submit_tag 'Log In', class: 'button-class' %>
```